# set the dragend event in angular-google-maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I am using this libary to create a google map in my angularjs (v 1.2.15) webapp:
https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/google-map

My goal is to capture the event when the user dragend the map with the mouse. I looked up the google maps API documentation and found the dragend event listener: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

I was able to initialize my map, but for some reason my dragend event listener does not work. 
Here is how I initialize my map with the angular-google-maps libary:

```
angular.module('appMaps', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $log, $timeout) {
    angular.extend($scope, {
      map: {
        center: {
          latitude: 42.3349940452867,
          longitude: -71.0353168884369
        },
        zoom: 7,
        events: {
          dragend: function() {
            alert('the map was dragged by the user')
          }
        },
        markers: [],
        // ..
        // ..
    });
  });
```

Here is my plunkr where everything works except the dragend listener:
http://plnkr.co/edit/AjnF4W5TB4cGSb59ete6?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `dragend` event is not getting fired since it is not attached to a map object. To attach event to a map object you need to utilize `events` attribute of `ui-gmap-google-map` directive like this:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map events="map.events" center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options">
```

where

```
.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, $log, $timeout) {
        angular.extend($scope, {
            map: {

                events: {
                    dragend: function () {
                        alert('dragend')
                    }
                },
                //the remaining code is omitted for clarity
            }
        });
    });
```

[Modified plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FfR2YX8jotGEIXLDva8b?p=preview)